# Changing navbar-fixed-top to navbar-static-top creates empty space above header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

The page in question is located here: http://deancraneproperties.com/rental-property-calculator/

When changing the header class from navbar-fixed-top to navbar-static-top, it creates an 80 pixel white space above the header. I can, of course, fix this by setting the margin-top to -80px, but I was wondering if anyone had an explanation as to why that is there, or has a better fix that mentioned above.

Here is the html in question:

```
<header id="header" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Y'all rock! Thanks for the quick responses, explanations and fixes. It's the simple things that you get stuck on that make you go crazy. lol.

Comment: Im not sure im seeing any white spaces. To be more precise what browser are you working with

Comment: I tried in different browser as well works fine on everything 'chrome', 'firefox' and `safari` dnt know about `ie`

Comment: I am using Chrome. Should have mentioned that. Also, currently, it is set to navbar-fixed-top so the white space is not there. If you where to change it to navbar-static-top using developer tools you will see it.

Comment: @Benjamin he has not changed the navbar to fixed on the live site he provided. So it does work as a fixed nav but if you change it to static then you will see the gap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is because your body tag for the whole page has a padding of 80px.

```
<body class="page page-id-381 page-template-default">
```

Im not sure if you added it or not. But if that body tag did not have an 80px padding then when you have it set to navbar-fixed-top then your content would actually slide up underneath your navbar. When you have a fixed navbar you need to leave a spacer for it so your content starts below the navbar not actually hidden underneath it.

If you remove the padding from your body tag then you should be good to go with a static navbar.

Answer (score 5):

The body element has 80px of `padding-top` applied to it. Remove this and it will resolve the issue.

When the navbar is fixed, it is not in the normal document flow and the padding is ignored by the navbar (but the rest of the non-fixed elements get pushed down by the padding to make room for the fixed navbar, which is the whole point of the `padding-top:80px;` being applied to the body), but when it is not fixed, the navbar will become part of the document flow and be pushed down by the padding of the body.

Comment: I wouldnt say the padding is ignored. But rather the fixed nav-bar ignores the padding. The padding it self is still there and all other elements respect it.

Comment: @GifCo agreed, lengthy explanations were never my strong suit ;)

Comment: Haha i hear you! What makes so much sense in your head sometimes looks like gibberish when you write it down! I do that a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you did that for intention but when you used `fixed` elements it will taking the entire width and floating top of your content unless you give them `z-index` since your header is on top the next content to go beneath your header to make them appear it below padding top will help you to achieve it.

Remove `padding-top:80px;` from your `body`

Comment: He was asking for an explination of why it was there. He already had a simple fix that worked.

Comment: @GifCo and that the reason